# how to share my research to maximum people across the globe?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, citations, online-publication

I found something very novel during my Ph.D. and we have published this finding. However, many people don't believe in our work and it has been a year since I published my paper but I found very few groups citing this work. Scientists from renowned institutes are writing commentaries about the false belief that they have had for over more than 50 years. I feel really disappointed that people are occupied with fixed beliefs and the media gives full coverage to their research. They are spreading wrong information and this information is being taught to students during their school life. All textbooks in biology keep on talking about that belief. Though I am not the first one to discover something novel in this field but my research has provided evidence that the discovery was not cooked up. I believe that my research although very basic will change the course of this field. One such example is the discovery of the process of neurogenesis in the adult brain. Initially, people didn't believe it but later a simple experiment using BrdU proved that neurons are regenerated in the adult brain.
Please guide me on how to convince scientists around the globe. Can I send links to my papers to them so that they can read and repeat the finding? Will it give a negative impression? Please tell me how to spread awareness.
I am not the first one who made this discovery but the evidence provided by my study will significantly contribute to the current understanding of this process.

Comment: To address this question in a good way, could you answer the following: (a) Is your research actually published in a good reputable journal? Papers in not-so-great journals will get unnoticed if there are contradictory paper in high-ranking journals (as the latter's quality standards are normally higher). (b) Is there are a particular reason why you write about "beliefs" on a scientific question? If there was a dominant theory before that your paper disproved or showed to be highly implausible, then say so. if not, then....well, are you sure that you have a strong point?

Comment: My research is published in stem cell reviews and reports which is a good journal with impact factor of 6. But contradictory papers are published in nature. I want to disseminate latest advancement and request scientist to follow our protocol and see if they can find what we have found. Secondly, I am more than 100% sure that my findings will add to latest advancement in the field and it will lead to re writing of textbooks.

Comment: @mini: After reading your question and your comments so far, I strongly suggest that the very first thing you should do is to realize that beliefs and rhetorics are not useful to convince other people in the sciences. You say that you "strongly believe" and that you are "more than 100% sure" - but why should anyone care how strongly you believe something or whether you say your are sure about it? If you want to convince others of your scientific results, this "I strongly believe and am very sure" rhetoric does yourself a great disservice.

Comment: I totally agree with you and I will be very careful while presenting my work. But I have found evidence to support my finding. I also agree that others should repeat the findings.

Comment: I have found specific structures in mice which scientific community has long questioned. So, it's not about cheap idea. My paper gives answers to the arguments raised by the scientific community using confocal microscopy and live cell imaging. I also tracked cells using brdu to prove that they are proliferating. I have also used FACS to sort cells and transplant in mice. So it's not that basic. What I mean to say is that lineage tracing provides the best answer to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be always keeping in mind the possibility you are simply wrong. I have to disagree with DCTLib here: the implicit belief in that you are not going crazy and are able to reason properly gets challenged in situations like this.
Now, let us assume you are certain that your study is properly done and convincing enough to challenge the existing body of work in your field (how does your experiment compare to those that established this notion? Are sample sizes sufficient? Are alternative explanations ruled out? - answers to those questions should provide you with good opening arguments). In this case, you disseminate your results like any others - through your network, by attending relevant conferences and, possibly, directly contacting other researchers.

Bugging others to read your papers would most certainly give a negative impression, especially if it is an unsolicited contact. There are different types of events where researchers allocate time to absorb new ideas, use those. Give your talk a catchy title. Argue with people. Grow your network. If your research undermines key assumptions made by big papers in the field, do more research on these "hot" topics using what you have learned and make sure your theory offers a better explanation of experimental results observed by others as well. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you but I have done basic experiments first. Then, used my imagination to unravel this process. I am pretty sure that my findings will prove true one day. Secondly, I read all the criticism , others made about the discovery and I have answered all those questions  in my paper. Unfortunately, we don't have lineage tracing facility in our lab. Otherwise, we would have used that technique. I also strongly believe if some reputed lab with good infrastructure repeats our experiments carefully, they will definitely find what we found and using advanced techniques, we can convince the world.

Comment: Unfortunately, as they say, ideas are cheap. If you find yourself in a situation where you are resource-starved to do great research, well, you are not the only one. I would suggest looking out for an opportunity to travel to a lab with good infrastructure and work there first. Either way, you (in a broad sense, as in, your lab) would probably need to secure funding for either expanding your own facilities (hard) or using someone else's. If even your lab is not fully on board with it, you have to sort that out first.

Comment: I have found specific structures in mice which scientific community has long questioned. So, it's not about cheap idea. My paper gives answers to the arguments raised by the scientific community using confocal microscopy and live cell imaging.  I also tracked cells using brdu to prove that they are proliferating. I have also used FACS to sort cells and transplant in mice. So it's not that basic. What I mean to say is that lineage tracing provides the best answer to the problem. I also strongly believe that imagination is more important than knowledge as is said by einstein.

Comment: Upvoted, but I don't see where your answer goes against my comment made to the original post. Perhaps you refer to "are you sure that you have a good point?", but that was really not a rhetorical question, but rather the request for an answer with a line of reasoning that helps answering the overall question "189735".

Comment: @DCTLib I've referred to (b) specifically, yes. Sorry for misunderstanding; you were right and I was overthinking it. There is a place for beliefs in in scientific research, but only when all the earlier steps were rigorously done. I have indeed jumped to "what to do if you know you are right", while you seemingly were angling for the OP to provide their reasoning so to help to work on it if/as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Even when assuming that you are correct, this takes time. Consider how long it takes you to go from an idea, to a draft, to a published paper. Most references will be from the time of idea generation or before - thus your paper can only be cited in those studies that have been started within the past year. Textbooks are even worse, they can take years to write and rewrite. And of course you don't want to make a big point in a book that hasn't been confirmed by anyone else.

In the meantime: give talks, go to conferences and research groups that might be interested or work on similar topics, and present your ideas/findings, and discuss them with those people.